# Error en subconsulta anidada en WHERE SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, subconsultas

Tengo un problema al hacer una subconsulta para extraer datos en mis tablas. Me piden lo siguiente:

"Los resultados deben cumplir con varios criterios: La suma de los pagos debe ser mayor que la suma de todos los pagos recibidos por el empleado que tiene Rut: 11630572 en el mes de agosto de este año."
Intenté arreglarlo con este código, haciendo una comparación de consultas sumadas, pero me deja todo en blanco, sin datos:

```
SELECT c.desc_categoria_emp, e.nombre_emp||' '|| e.appaterno_emp||' '||apmaterno_emp AS "NOMBRE_COMPLETO",
p.nombre_provincia, TO_CHAR(e.numrut_emp, '99G999G999')||'-'||e.dvrut_emp AS "RUT", 
TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(pa.fecha_pago, 4,2)) AS "MES",
sum(pa.monto_a_cancelar) AS VENTAS_MENSUALES 

FROM
categoria_empleado c join empleado e
ON (c.id_categoria_emp)=(e.id_categoria_emp)
JOIN pago_atencion pa 
ON (e.numrut_emp)=(pa.numrut_emp)
JOIN comuna co 
ON (co.cod_comuna)=(e.id_comuna)
JOIN provincia p
ON (p.cod_provincia) = (co.cod_provincia) 
group by c.desc_categoria_emp,
e.nombre_emp||' '|| e.appaterno_emp||' '||apmaterno_emp, p.nombre_provincia, 
TO_CHAR(e.numrut_emp, '99G999G999')||'-'||e.dvrut_emp, TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(pa.fecha_pago, 4,2))


having sum(pa.monto_a_cancelar) >

(SELECT sum(pa.monto_a_cancelar)
from PAGO_ATENCION pa
where EXTRACT(month from pa.fecha_pago) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE -4)
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pa.fecha_pago) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)  
) 


ORDER BY "RUT", "VENTAS_MENSUALES" ;
```

Entonces... no encuentro otra forma de hacer lo que me piden, igualando el mes solicitado y el año actual, un informe paramétrico ... si alguien me puede ayudar por favor, Gracias.

Comment: Bueno... a ver... es muy dificil ayudarte sin saber nada de que son todos esos campos.. puede venir en blanco por mil motivos... que no haya registros, que este mal un join... consejo: empeza de a una cosa por vez, primero saca ese valor de agosto.. despues busca  la suma de los pagos, sin mas que eso... despues anda agregando todo, de a una cosa por vez.... asi vas a poder depurar y ver que esta fallando...

Comment: ah.. y esto es oracle o mysql? porque son dos bases totalmente distintas...